# Touchscreen sample rate for human interface device

Tags: touch, sample-rate

What is a good rule of thumb for acceptable touch sample rates for human interface devices?

For example, it is pretty widely known that a visual screen refresh rate of 60Hz is at the upper limits of human perception.  Is there a similar number for touch sample rates so that interactions feel "instantaneous" to a "typical" human.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I to was looking for an answer to this. When I stumbled upon someone that gave the answer during a github change:

https://github.com/pershoot/gtab-2632/issues/1

"Touchscreen sample rate is 25Hz which makes scrolling, using the unlock screen, pulling the drawer down, etc, appear jerky as the effective framerate is reduced to 25fps. This change bumps the sample rate up to 100Hz, which feels great. I haven't had time to test other sample rates yet, but presumably a 15ms sleep should be good too (for tagetting 60-75Hz)."

My own experience supports this conclusion.